# How to cast a mongoose aggregate result to a specific document schema type?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, casting, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Consider the following aggretation:

```
let getUsersWithNoPersonsPromise = () => {

        let pipeline = [
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "persons",
                    localField: "id",
                    foreignField: "person_id",
                    as: "persons_users"
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    "persons_users:0": {
                        $exists: false
                    }
                }
            }
        ];


        return User.aggregate(pipeline).exec();
}
```

How to I cast the `$match` result to be of type UserModel ? I´m getting plain javascript objects on it and I expect to receive mongoose User type objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the result of the aggregation query and simply instantiate new objects by iterating through the array of results, like this (assuming you are using async await);

```
let people = await getUsersWithNoPersonsPromise()
people = people.map(p => new Person(p))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
const { Query } = require('mongoose');
const mongooseQuery = new Query();

// pass the model and filter to mongoose to cast
// you can add this to pre aggregation middleware
mongooseQuery.cast(Model, filter);
```